# PHP count number of non-empty input data in an array in each for loop

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I have a form which update multiple rows of input data into my sql. Each row has 3 input fields in the form. I'm trying to count number of empty data in each row in each for loop and update the number into SQL by calculating into percentage. For example, in one row, out of the 3 input fields, only 2 input fields are filled therefore the percentage should be (2 / 3) * 100 = 67 (rounded up). How do i do that? Below is my code. Please check if it make sense to you.

```
<?php
        $execute = false;
        $pr = 0;
        $userid_array = $_POST['userid_array'];     
        $access_array = $_POST['access_array'];
        $ic_array = $_POST['ic_array'];
        $email_array = $_POST['email_array'];
        
        foreach($userid_array as $key => $userid)
        {
            $array_count = 0;
            $access = $access_array[$key];
            $ic = $ic_array[$key];
            $email = $email_array[$key];
            
            $array_count = count(array_filter($access,$ic,$email)); //Count number of non-empty array elements
            
            $pr_percent = round(($array_count/3)*100, 0); //number of non-empty array elements divided by total number of input field multiply by 100
            
            $tsql = "UPDATE MASTER SET [Access] = ?, [IC] = ?, [Email] = ?, [pr_percent] = ? WHERE user_id = ?"; 
            $params_tsql = array($access,$ic,$email,$pr_percent,$userid);
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params_tsql);
                

            if($stmt)
            {
                  $execute = true;
            } 
            else
            {
                  $execute = false;
                  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
        }

        if($execute){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

?>
```

Comment: what problems are you encountering? are there error messages?

Comment: @Kevin It only printed 'failed' based on my echo message.

Comment: Your code shouldn't execute at all, `array_filter($access,$ic,$email)` should exit with a TypeError as `$access` is not an array. It should be `array_filter(array($access,$ic,$email))`

Answer (score 0):

@Nick Thank you so much. How could i be so careless.

Below is my answer

```
$array_count = count(array_filter(array($access,$ic,$email)));
```